# Why does selectionBinding on Ember.Select not respect contentBinding when Ember.Select is not subclassed?

Tags: ember.js

When I subclass Ember.Select the selection binding can successfully be set to `'content.selection'` where `content` is a controller. When I try to do this inline in a template, the binding does not connect. This problem can be seen in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cmQsX/

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController" selectionBinding="content.selection" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" }}
    {{view ResAdmin.foo}}

    Selected: {{ResAdmin.selectedRestaurant.priceCategory.name}}
</script>​
```

The code:

```
ResAdmin = Ember.Application.create({});

ResAdmin.adminController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    selection: null,
    content: [
        {
        id: '92E9862E-DAE5-4CC8-ACDF-7E6418641F7D',
        name: "$"},
    {
        id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
        name: "$$"},
    {
        id: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145',
        name: "$$$"},
    {
        id: '417993DB-48BF-4BA9-BE0A-D6A53C6D8325',
        name: "$$$$"}
    ],
    getObjectById: function(id) {
        return this.get('content').filterProperty('id', id).get('firstObject');
    }
});

ResAdmin.selectedRestaurant = Ember.Object.create({
    priceCategoryBinding: 'ResAdmin.adminController.selection'
});

ResAdmin.foo = Ember.Select.extend({
    contentBinding:"ResAdmin.adminController",
    selectionBinding:"content.selection",
    optionLabelPath:"content.name",
    optionValuePath:"content.id"})

var defaultItem = ResAdmin.adminController.getObjectById('47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145');
console.log(defaultItem);
ResAdmin.adminController.set('selection', defaultItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

It works when you specify the selection as `selectionBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.selection"`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/rXudx/:

```
{{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController"
    selectionBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.selection"
    optionLabelPath="content.name"
    optionValuePath="content.id" }}
```

---

This seems like a bug. You should file a ticket on [GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues).